# How to extend the context object of a GraphQL call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, passport.js

I'm having the following GraphQL server call in a standard module:

```
export default () => {
    return graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true,
        pretty: true,
        formatError: error => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack,
            path: error.path
        })
    });
};
```

That is used together with passport:

```
app.use(
    "/graphql",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    appGraphQL()
);
```

Everything is working file. Passport extends my `req` to get a logged user object that is used on my GraphQL calls to queries or mutations:

```
...
    resolve(source, args, context) {
        console.log("CURRENT USER OBJECT")
        console.log(context.user)
...
```

All fine.

Now I need to extend my context to add some custom resolvers, so my first try is:

```
export default () => {
    return graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true,
        pretty: true,
        context: resolvers,
        formatError: error => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack,
            path: error.path
        })
    });
};
```

As GraphQL docs says, this overrides the original req context and my `context.user` on queries and mutations stops working.

How can I properly extend the current context to add some more fields, instead of overriding it? Another unsuccessfull try:

```
export default (req) => {
    return graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true,
        pretty: true,
        context: {
            user: req.user,
            resolvers: resolvers
        },
        formatError: error => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack,
            path: error.path
        })
    });
};
```

This approach is not working... I'm getting the following error:

```
  user: req.user,
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

[edit]
My latest try is from my example on [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data/):

```
export default () => {
    return graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true,
        pretty: true,
        context: ({ req }) => ({
            user: req.user
        }),
        formatError: error => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack,
            path: error.path
        })
    });
};
```

Now my context is a function in my resolver:

```
console.log(context)
console.log(context.user)
```

Returns:

```
[Function: context]
undefined
```

Getting crazy with this simple thing...

Comment: If you're getting that TypeError, it means you're not passing `req` to the exported function wherever it's being called in the rest of your code.

Comment: Sure... Check my last try... crazy...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using `express-graphql`, `graphqlHTTP` is a function that takes some configuration parameters and returns an express middleware function. Normally, it's used like this:

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({ ... })
)
```

However, instead of an object, graphqlHTTP can also take **a function that returns an object** as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options).

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP((req, res, graphQLParams) => {
    return { ... }
  })
)
```

In this way, you can utilize the `req`, `res` or `graphQLParams` parameters inside your configuration object.

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP((req, res, graphQLParams) => {
    return {
      schema,
      // other options
      context: {
        user: req.user,
        // whatever else you want
      }
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: Great explanation! The parameters comes from `graphqlHTTP`, not from the `app.use()` itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried getting the data from the context in my resolver after passing it to my **graphqlHTTP** function to no avail. I later tried printing my request object and voila, it worked.

```
// app.js

app.use(
    "/graphql",
    graphqlHTTP((req, res) => {
        return {
            schema: schema,
            rootValue: resolver,
            graphiql: true,
            context: { user, req, res }
        }                                                   
    })
);
```

```js
// api.resolver.js

getUsers: ({}, request, context) => {
    console.log(request.user)
    return Object.values(db.user);
}
```